# Error al compilar proyecto aspx en visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Buen dia a todos, estoy creando un sitio web pero al correrlo IE me genera este error, les agradezco mucho su ayuda, saludos!

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: site    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
>   of valid values. Parameter name: site]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags
>   hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception
>   appDomainCreationException) +280
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range
>   of valid values. Parameter name: site]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10074760
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: Parece ser algo que falla cuando inicia el sitio, revisas el global.asax si has definido algo en la inicializacion?

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion, lo publicare como respuesta para futuros casos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, por si alguien mas llegara a tener el mismo problema la solucion es la siguiente:

Control panel > Programs and Feautures >  Turn Windows Feautres on or off

Y habilitar Internet Information Services (IIS), despues reiniciar la computadora y listo!

Saludos!